# Questions about union of conjugates and index of subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

For the following question:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.  Prove that $|\cup_{a\in G} a^{-1}Ha|\leq 1 + |G| - [G:H]$

What do conjugates have to do with $[G:H]$?  I just learn about the definition of what a conjugate is.  I have not learn about the class equation.  I try looking up from other abstract algebra text, and I was not able to find anything related to this question in the section related to the class equation.  The question is taken from question 20 of chapter 8's supplementary exercises from the book A First Course in Group Theory by Bijan Davvaz,

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You ask:

> What do conjugates have to do with $[G:H]$?

Well, the number of conjugates of $H$ is $[G:N_G(H)]$, the index of the normalizer of $H$ in $G$.

Since $H \leq N_G(H) \leq G$, you get $[G:H] = [G:N_G(H)][N_G(H):H]$. So that is one answer to your question.

In particular, the number of conjugates is $\leq [G:H]$. As a hint, you can use this fact to prove inequality in the question.

Comment: do you have any reference concerning the relation between conjugates, normalizer and centralizer in terms of counting principles.  I see that in most abstract algebra texts, there are lots of properties listed for cosets, but not so much for conjugates.  I think that is one of the reasons why I have difficulty with this question.  Also, as far as how normalizer, centralizers, conjugates, orbits, etc relate to each other in terms of the topic of counting.  It seems that other than the class equation, there is not much that are talked about in many beginning algebra texts.

Comment: The fact that $[G:N_G(H)]$ is the number of conjugates should be in any basic group theory text. This is also a special case of the orbit-stabilizer theorem. Look at e.g. Rotman, Introduction to the Theory of Groups, Chapter 3, section on $G$-sets.

Comment: ah kk.  Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

And one more hint:
$$
\bigcup_{a\in G}a^{-1}Ha=\left(\bigcup_{a\in G}(a^{-1}Ha\setminus\{1\})\right)\cup\{1\}.\tag1
$$

**Addition.**

All the hints required to solve the problem:

1. Formula $(1)$.
2. The number of different subgroups of the form $a^{-1}Ha$ is not larger than the index $|G:H|$.
   (This follows from the simple statement: If $Ha=Hb$, then $a^{-1}Ha=b^{-1}Hb$.)
3. Lagrange's theorem $|G|=|H|\cdot|G:H|$.

Comment: what is the intuition behind $a^{-1}Ha\setminus\{1\}$?  I see that you add it back too.  As I asked spin, I can't find any good algebra texts that talks about properties of conjugates the way cosets are discussed.

Comment: Note that $1$ is removed from each subgroup $a^{-1}Ha$, but added only once. To emphasize this I added one more pair of brackets to the formula.

Comment: can I ask if this topic is part of which group theory topic in introductory abstract algebra course?  Does it have to do with the orbit stabilizer theorem or class equation.  When you are subtracting the identity element from each conjugate element, aren't you subtracting too much by only adding back the identity back only once.  I can't separate cosets and conjugate elements in the sense I don't know if all the properties for cosets carry over to conjugate elements.

Comment: @Seth  I expanded my answer a little bit (no normalizers or centralizers are required).

Comment: so conjugate elements are like cosets, meaning they partition a group the way coset does.  Also, does it have to do with the following problem:   Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $H\leq G.$  Assume that $\bigcup_{g\in G}g^{-1}Hg=G$.  Show that $|G|\leq 1 + |G:N_{G}(H)|(|H|-1).$

Comment: Or in an equivalent formulation in another text: If $H\neq G$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$, show $G\neq \bigcup_{g\in G}g^{-1}Hg$.  Hint:  Reduce to the case of $H$ not normal so that $|G/N_{G}(H)|\geq 2,$  Show that the number of distinct sets of the form $g^{-1}Hg$ is $|G|/|N_{G}(H)|$ and show that $\bigcup_{g\in G}g^{-1}Hg\leq 1+(|H-1|)(|G|/|N_{G}(H)|)$

Answer (score 1):

> What do conjugates have to do with $[G:H]$?

$G$ acts by left multiplication on the left quotient set $G/H$, whose size is $[G:H]$, and the pointwise stabilizer of $aH\in G/H$ is precisely the conjugate to $H$ by $a$, namely $aHa^{-1}$.